# Error with Sign Up using Parse (Swift) on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

This is my current code, it only works with username and password but when I want to add more fields like firstname lastname phonenumber it gives me an error stating "PFUser does not have a memeber named firstname...etc..."

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
 func processSignUp() {

    var userField = emlField.text
    var usrPassword = pwdField.text
    var firstField = frstField.text
    var lastField = lstField.text
    var phoneNumber = phoneField.text

    // Ensure username is lowercase
    userField = userField.lowercaseString

    // Add email address validation

    // Start activity indicator

    // Create the user
    var user = PFUser()
    user.username = userField
    user.password = usrPassword
    user.firstName = frstField //ERROR HERE
    user.lastName = lstField //ERROR HERE
    user.phoneNumber = phoneField //ERROR HERE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are custom fields and u reach them with

```
user["firstname"]
user["lastname"]
```

etc ...